# MacOSX 10.10 Outlook 2011 blur background in navigation pane

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, osx-yosemite

Someone knows how to bring back the solid background color ?
This occurs only after I upgraded to OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

The blurry background occurs over anything in the background, and since i have a changing wallpaper - it simply driving me crazy.

More over, when the window is *inactive* the navigation pane's background becomes a solid color background ( just like it was in MacOSX 10.9 )

[image]

Comment: This is part of "vibrancy" in Yosemite, and it gets applied to sidebars & tool bars. Since Office 2011 folder pane is a sidebar, this vibrancy effects gets applied to it. You can turn off transparency through the acessibility control panel > display > reduce transparency.

Comment: Genius ! place it as an answer so I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of "vibrancy" in Yosemite, and it gets applied to sidebars & tool bars. Since Office 2011 folder pane is a sidebar, this vibrancy effects gets applied to it. You can turn off transparency through the `acessibility in control panel > display > reduce transparency`.