# MacOSX 10.10 Outlook 2011 folders are grayed out

Tags: osx-yosemite, microsoft-outlook-2011

So after adjusting the blurry background in the new MacOSX 10.10
( described here: [MacOSX 10.10 Outlook 2011 blur background in navigation pane](https://superuser.com/questions/903760/macosx-10-10-outlook-2011-blur-background-in-navigation-pane) )

Now I see the folders in gray color, but some stayed black, not sure why ?
is there any change to adjust it ?

[image]

All the subfolder are also grayed out ( not disabled though .. )

The changes I did:

- System preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Reduce Transparency
- System preferences -> General -> use dark menu bar and dock

Note: even when I revert these changes .. I still don't get the blurry background back nor the folder colors ...

Comment: It's actually all the real-native sidebars in this OSX .. ( except Finder )

Answer (score 2):

System preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Select Increase Contrast

Comment: It does what I need, but all the other windows (Finder / buttons borders etc .. ) looks old with a black border around it ... any other idea ?